# How to enumerate all combinations of $n$ binary variables s.t. their sum is $k$?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, enumeration

Suppose we are given $n$ variables $X_i, i=1,\dots,n$, each taking values from $\{0,1\}$, and a constant integer $k$ with $ 0\leq k \leq n$.

What are some efficient ways to enumerate all possible combinations of values of $X_i$'s subject to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k$?

A naive way is to first enumerate one by one all possible combinations of values of $X_i$'s without the constraint  $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k$, and for each combination, check if it satisfies  $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k$ (if it does, keep it; if it doesn't, discard it).

That naive way may be inefficient.
For example, when $k=1$, a more efficient way will be for each $i$, letting $X_i=1$ and $X_j =0, \forall j \neq i$.

So I wonder for general $k$, what are some efficient ways to do the above task?

Comment: Are you asking for an ${n}\choose{k}$-iterator?  You can check out this source code of [NChooseKIterator](https://github.com/drange/Grapher/blob/master/src/no/uib/ii/algo/st8/util/NChooseKIterator.java).

Comment: @PålGD: Thanks, and close (probably yet). Is there some source for description of the algorithm? I am not familiar with Java, but I will have to implement it in Matlab.

Comment: See also this stackoverflow question: [n choose k implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095407/n-choose-k-implementation).

Comment: What does "efficient" mean here? Note that for $k=n/2$, we must enumerate exponentially many (in $n$) items.

Comment: @Raphael he probably means in true ${n}\choose{k}$ time and not, say $n!$ time.  Also, important might be to have a polynomial delay, maybe even linear in $n$.

Comment: I would vote to close this question as this is either a mathematica/matlab what-ever implementation question and has been answered for different languages elsewhere.

Comment: @Raphael: As to efficiency, see the example I gave in my post, where you don't have to enumerate all possible combinations without the constraint.

Comment: Efficiency is not big-oh, but compact ways of computing the next item. So, elegant iterators. With combinatorial explosions that can save quite some (real) time. Knuth's Volume 4 has extensive info on generating partitions, combinations, and partitions, so it is not a what-ever implementation question. (end of proof by authority)

Comment: @Tim: $\binom{n}{n/2}$ is exponential in $n$ *itself*, so even if you only ever check valid combinations, runtime is exponential.

Answer (score 4):

First, separate the set of variables $I = \{1,\dots,n\}$ according to their values:

$\qquad\begin{align}
  I_+ &= \{ i \mid X_i = 1\} \text{ and} \\
  I_- &= \{ i \mid X_i = 0\} \;.
\end{align}$

Let $n_+ = |I_+|$ and $n_- = |I_-|$.

Given $X_1, \dots, X_n$ and $k$, it is clear that we have to choose $k$ indices from $I_+$ and arbitrarily many from $I_-$. That means we will have to output

$\qquad \binom{n_+}{k} \cdot 2^{n_-}$

solutions. Note that if we assume $\binom{a}{b} = 0$ for $b<0$ and $b>a$, this extends nicely to inputs that allow no solution.

Generating all valid solutions in a list can be done by two nested recursions: the outer creates all $k$-subsets of $I_+$, the inner all subsets of $I_-$. This way, no illegal solutions are investigated, which is as efficient as you can expect (up to list operations).

```
  outer(I+, 0, I-) = inner(I-)
| outer(I+, k, I-) =
    result = []
    foreach ( i in I+ ) {
      suffices = outer(I+ - i, k-1, I-)
      result ++= (suffices map { [i] ++ _ })
    }
    return result

  inner([])      = []
  inner(x::rest) = 
    smaller = inner(rest);
    return smaller ++ (smaller map { [x] ++ _ })
```

If you want an iterator, note that you can replace recursion with stacks (which allows you to compute it step by step) and emit solutions in the innermost call of `inner`. Of course, you'll have to reverse the way solutions are constructed (while descending, as opposed to during ascension as I did above).